# Error running App: No JDK specified

Tags: java, android, android-studio, java-9

I have installed **Android studio 3.0.1** and when i run the app he gives me an error

```
Error running App: No JDK specified
```

Note that i have installed JDK 9 and I made two environment variable **`JAVA_HOME`** and **`JDK_HOME`** and edit path variable
and in project structure I choose  **JDK 9** but I am also failed to run!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try following, it did work for me:

Go to **File -> Project Structure -> SDK Location** and check if the path for SDK and JDK location specified by you is correct. If its not then set the correct path.

For me it looks like this:

```
Android SDK location:
C:\Users\JDoe\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

JDK location:
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre
```